# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox call eval_in_page and then dead object error

Tags: perl, firefox, www-mechanize-firefox

I am using `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`.

When I call `eval_in_page` a second time, it dies with `dead object` error.

Here is my code

```
$mech->get($url);

$mech->eval_in_page('some_fun1(123)');
my @divs = $mech->xpath('//div[@class="sometext"]');
my @data = map { $_->{innerHTML} } @divs;
#...

$mech->eval_in_page('some_fun2(456)');  #dead object error...
my @divs_fun2 = $mech->xpath('//div[@class="sometext"]');
my @data_fun2 = map { $_->{innerHTML} } @divs_fun2;
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Firefox 15 introduced a major improvement in memory usage, by
>   disallowing add-ons to keep references to DOM objects after their
>   parent document was destroyed. This eliminates the most common cause
>   of memory leaks in add-ons, and should reduce memory consumption for
>   many users.

https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/09/12/what-does-cant-access-dead-object-mean/